# How to change colors on webpage (non-owner) so chart elements can be distinguished ? (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, html, firefox-extensions, webpage

Is there a way to change the colors on one of the elements in ESPN's game flow chart, so it's easier to tell the two teams scores apart? (Why the colors are so close is mystifying.) Maybe there's a plugin that allow you to customize a webpage?

[image]

Comment: It may not be the simplest way, but you can open developer tools (F12) and manipulate the CSS and HTML directly. Or by right-clicking and inspecting element.

Comment: I tried that before posting here.   Finding the right value is hopeless.  Right-clicking and selecting the style editor results in a whole lot of possible code.

Comment: For reference, the OP is on a page similar to [this](https://www.espn.in/mens-college-basketball/game/_/gameId/401408621), where the chart reffered is a `canvas` element

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the extension "violentmonkey"?

It can inject js code into any webpage that in turn can manipulate each dom-element, which includes the styles.

This code can be hand written by yourself or downloaded from a repository, which might already have the code you need.

Comment: Suggesting tools is OK, but you need to tell how to use this to solve the problem asked, which you haven't yet done. Right now this is just a comment.